# A Sylow $2-$subgroup of SL(2,q) is irreducible

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $q$ an odd prime power. By a classic result, a Sylow $2-$subgroup of $SL(2,q)$ is generalized quaternion. How can I show that it is an (absolutely) irreducible subgroup of $GL(2,q)$ ? 
I have looked at Dixon's Problems in Group Theory but have not found any results about how to show that a given subgroup is irreducible. Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: If it was reducible, then it would be the sum of two $1$-dimensional representations, in which case it would be abelian - but it is not.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I see that more generally any non-abelian subgroup of $GL(2,q)$ is irreducible.

Comment: That's not true when the order of the subgroup is divisible by $p$, where $q$ is a power of the prime $p$. There is a nonabelian subgroup of order $q(q-1)$ which is reducible.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot we are not in the algebraically closed setting.

Comment: If you want to ask an additional question, please open a new question and do not edit the old one. If Derek Holt's comments already gave you a complete answer, please ask him to write them up as an answer.